# POSIX shell compatible and POSIX conforming dirname implementation

Tags: strings, bash, shell, sh, posix

The discussion in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32354836/258523) made me wonder how hard it would be to write a built-in only version of `dirname`.

This is what I ended up with but I'm reasonably confident it should be able to be improved (I haven't spent much time thinking about it yet).

Any improvements/suggestions are welcome.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

p=$1
alt=$2
skip78=

stripslashes() {
    i=$1
    while [ "$i" != "$o" ]; do
        o=$i
        i=${i%/}
    done
    eval "$2=\$i"
}

[ "$p" = '//' ] || {
    case "$p" in
        *[!/]*|'')
            stripslashes "$p" p
            case "$p" in
                */*)
                    p=${p%/*}
                    ;;
                *)
                    p=.
                    skip78=skip78
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
        *)
            p=/
            skip78=skip78
            ;;
    esac
}
[ -n "$skip78" ] || {
    { [ "$p" != '//' ] || [ -z "$alt" ]; } && {
        stripslashes "$p" p
        [ -z "$p" ] && p=/
    }
}

printf -- %s\\n "$p"
```

The [POSIX spec for `dirname` is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html):

> 1. If *string* is `//`, skip steps 2 to 5.
> 2. If *string* consists entirely of <slash> characters, *string* shall be set to a single <slash> character. In this case, skip
>      steps 3 to 8.
> 3. If there are any trailing <slash> characters in *string*, they shall be removed.
> 4. If there are no <slash> characters remaining in *string*, *string* shall be set to a single <period> character. In this case, skip steps 5 to 8.
> 5. If there are any trailing non- <slash> characters in *string*, they shall be removed.
> 6. If the remaining *string* is `//`, it is implementation-defined whether steps 7 and 8 are skipped or processed.
> 7. If there are any trailing <slash> characters in *string*, they shall be removed.
> 8. If the remaining *string* is empty, *string* shall be set to a single <slash> character.

Update: Made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/deryni/9c67a908778c1a18405b).

Comment: bash is the only option possible or a awk, sed, ... could be used also ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu The idea was something to replace the sub-shell needed for calling `dirname`. So anything that needs a sub-shell mostly negates the purpose. In theory this script would be turned into a function like `stripslashes` that operates on its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a really compelling reason for this `eval` in `stripslashes`:

> ```
> eval "$2=\$i"
> ```

It's a dirty hack to update the parameter variable in-place.
But this is not a common practice, I don't know other commands or built-ins that work that way, and I would find such usage unexpected.
I would find it more usable if `stripslashes` behaved more like other commands do:

- print the result on `stdout`
- set the result in a designated variable (like `REPLY`)

That would be more in-line with common UNIX practices, and unsurprising, familiar.

---

As a minor nitpick, I avoid quoting when it's unnecessary.
For example instead of `[ "$p" != '//' ]`, I would write `[ "$p" != // ]`

---

Instead of this:

> ```
>         [ -z "$p" ] && p=/
> ```

This form is shorter:

```
        [ "$p" ] || p=/
```

---

This might be subjective, but I would rewrite this part using regular if-else:

> ```
> [ -n "$skip78" ] || {
>     { [ "$p" != '//' ] || [ -z "$alt" ]; } && {
>         stripslashes "$p" p
>         [ -z "$p" ] && p=/
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: We can't use stdout for stripslashes because that requires a sub-shell and at that point we are back to "just use dirname". We could just write into `p` directly by name but that makes `stripslashes` a one-use helper function as opposed to being generally useful written this way. With `bash` as opposed to `sh` I'd use `printf -v` there instead of `eval`. As to the quoting and the `-z` test those were to avoid possibly confusing people less familiar with the shell though `[ -n "$p" ] || p=/` might be better for that purpose as I imagine `-n` is much more commonly used than `-z`.

Comment: But actually I just realized that `: "${p:=/}"` is clearly the right way to do that bit.